# How to properly redirect IP address of server to Domain host name in Nginx with expressjs running as server

Tags: nginx, webserver

I'm currently trying to set up a web server with Nginx and ExpressJS. Currently, it works when I enter 123.456.789.999 in the address bar and it loads however I'm trying to properly redirect from 123.456.789.999 to example.com. I've tried to add a server block that listens at port 80 and permanently move it to example.com in the 2nd server block. But whenever I enter example.com in the address bar it does not load.

In my Domain Manager, I've set the following

```
| Record     | Name |      Value      | TTL   |
|------------|------|-----------------|-------|
|    A       |   @  | 123.456.789.999 | 1 Day |
|  CNAME     |  www |         @       | 1 Hour|
```

The rest are default values.

```
server {
            listen 80;
            listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html/;
    index index.html index.htm;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    location / {

        }
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name 123.456.789.999;
        return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: redirect from IP to domains sounds strange. However. What does `dig @8.8.8.8 example.com` Does it point to your IP address? I would not redirect but you are totally fine to add a default server showing so general page instead the domain is not configured on this server.

Comment: hey @Timo Stark, its actually my very first time trying to create my own web hosting server, i've read up quite a fair bit, i understand that people tend to use it as a reverse proxy while running server.js with any port number. is this the better alternative? and yes when i ran the ```dig``` command, it points to my public IP Address

Answer (score 1):

Having NGINX in front of your WebApps as a reverse Proxy is a very common use use, yes. First of all you should understand some basics.

The users of your services know the Domain `example.com`. Your Web/Proxy/App Servers IP address needs to be linked to the Domain using DNS. This step (looks like) is already done. Good job.

### NGINX proxy server setup

Given you are using nodeJS / express to run an App listening on port `3000` on `localhost` and you want this as your main app for `example.com`.

```sh
#Define an upstream block for your service.

upstream my-backend {
  server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

#Define your main server configuration

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://my-backend;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
  }
}
```

See the following reference: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/

It is important to understand the NGINX configuration syntax and how the configuration is organised to get the most out of it. I have a video about it. https://youtu.be/nhSYFL1tufM

Answer (score 0):

This thread looks a bit old (2+ yrs), but I came across to it yesterday while dealing with a similar problem myself. And this worked for me;

#nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  www.example.com;

    # redirect requests that doesn't include the server_name (i.e. made for the IP address) to it; 
    if ($host != $server_name) {
        return 301 $scheme://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
}
```